# Negative value in byte type

Tags: c#

I've just started struggling around C# and I have a question.

In the following code:

```
byte var = 0;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", ~var);
```

Why does it print -1? From http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson02 I've read that the byte range is from 0 to 255 and ~(00000000)_2 gives (11111111)_2 which is equal to (255)_10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value you are printing is not of type `byte`. It is of type `int`.

The `~` (bitwise not) operator is not defined for `byte`, but it is for `int`. Your code has an implicit widening conversion to `int`. Your code is roughly equivalent to this version that uses an explicit cast:

```
int temp = ~((int)var);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
```

The bitwise not operator inverts the bits to give the result `111....111` (base 2). This has the value -1 in the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

---

If you want the result to be a byte with value 255 you have to add an explicit cast:

```
byte x = 0;
byte result = (byte)~x;
```

Comment: +1 Nice and clear explanation. There is no `Console.WriteLine(byte)` overload.

Comment: Thanks, i searched the  'world' for this simple solution!